# Javascript getElementsByTagName returns empty list for some tags and works fine for some other tags

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I don't understand why for some tags the method `getElementsByTagName` is returning an empty list. This is a MWE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    
    <figure class="figure" id="other figure">
        <image src="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg" width="100%" style="max-height: 70vh"></image>
        <figcaption>I am a figcaption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    
    <float class="figure" id="my figure">
        <image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" width="100%" style="max-height: 70vh"></image>
        <caption>I am a caption</caption>
        <figcaption>I am a figcaption 2.</figcaption>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
    </float>
    
    <script>
    
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("float")); // Works fine with this custom tag
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("figure")); // Works fine
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("image")); // Fails, returns empty list with NON custom tag
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("caption")); // Fails, returns empty list
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("figcaption")); // Works fine
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("p")); // Works fine
    
    </script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Just in case the behavior of the previous snippet is browser-dependent, here is my result in screenshot format:

[image]

Comment: For `<image>` it's because the HTML parser will convert these to actual HTMLImageElement `<img>` automagically. For `<caption>` it should be in a `<table>` to be valid., otherwise it's just removed.

Comment: Please note that the HTML you've shown is invalid. HTML does not have a `float` element. If you want to create custom elements, these need to conform to custom element requirements to be valid, the minimum of which is that the element's tagname must consist of at least two, dash-separated words.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @connexo. It has to be pointed out, also, that the "invalid" elements I am using here have a more predictable and intuitive behavior than the standard `caption` and `image` elements. In fact my solution for the `caption` elements was to invent my own `floatcaption` tags and it works fine.

Comment: Invalid HTML is **never** an option. The argument *works fine* is not relevant. Writing code that relies on error tolerance of systems or unspecified behaviour that is observed at a certain point in time is **really bad development**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `IMG` or `img` instead of `image`.

Notes: [`<caption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption)

> The HTML `<caption>` element specifies the caption (or title) of a table.

```html
<body>
    
    <figure class="figure" id="other figure">
        <image src="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg" width="100%" style="max-height: 70vh"></image>
        <figcaption>I am a figcaption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    
    <float class="figure" id="my figure">
        <image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" width="100%" style="max-height: 70vh"></image>
        <table>
          <caption>I am a caption</caption>
        </table>
        <figcaption>I am a figcaption 2.</figcaption>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
    </float>
    
    <script>
    
        //console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("float")); // Works fine with this custom tag
        //console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("figure")); // Works fine
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("img")); // Fails, returns empty list with NON custom tag
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("caption")); // Fails, returns empty list
        //console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("figcaption")); // Works fine
        //console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("p")); // Works fine
    
    </script>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, so unpredictable. But it works. Thanks. Do you know the trick to get the `caption` elements?

Comment: this. and for caption, it even didn't load caption as a tag. So there is no caption tag

Comment: I see, using the "inspector" you can see what it is showing. This is very surprising to me because `image` and `caption` are standard tags. In view of this it seems better to invent my own `image_my` and `caption_my` tags and break the standard... So weird.

Comment: @user171780, *caption* elements should inside of a table.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer. This behavior is much against intuition and common sense.

Comment: If you want to back this answer with some specs: ["***A start tag whose tag name is "image"**  Parse error. Change the token's tag name to "img" and reprocess it. (Don't ask.)"*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody) and ["Contexts in which this element can be used: As the first element child of a table element."](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-caption-element)

Answer (score -1):

Run this line in the F12 Console to see which tags are of type `HTMLUnknownElement`

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("*")].map(el=>console.assert(!el.constructor.name.includes("Unknown"),el));
```